# How Do I Create a Static Background Image Using NextJS's Next/Image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I've been using Next/Image for everything lately because of Vercel's automatic image optimization service. I've been able to replace `background-image` in pretty much every use-case by using DIVs in conjunction with `z-index`, but I've had a heck of a time trying to get a background image to 1.) fill the entire viewport, and 2.) Not resize when the window shrinks.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to duplicate:

https://watson-vcard.netlify.app/index-dark-particles2.html

Here's an example of what I'm trying in NextJS:

```js
<div className="overflow-hidden">
  <Image 
    src={coverImg} 
    alt="Cover Image" 
    className="" fill 
  />
</div>
```

I'm also using TailwindCSS. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Here's what I ended up trying:

```js
// @/components/Layout/index.js

import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image';
import coverImg from '@/img/cover.jpg';

export default function Layout({ pageTitle, children }) {
    let titleConcat = "Jay Simons";
    if (pageTitle) titleConcat += " | " + pageTitle;

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{titleConcat}</title>
            </Head>
            <main className="h-screen text-white">
                <div className="flex fixed top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0" style={{ zIndex: -1 }}>
                    <div className="flex shrink-0">
                        <Image
                            src={coverImg}
                            alt="Cover Image"
                            className="mx-auto min-[1920px]:w-[100vw]"
                            width={1920}
                            height={1080}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

And

```js
// @/pages/index.js

import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image';
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'

import coverImg from '@/img/cover.jpg';

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="flex h-screen">
        <div className="w-[300px] bg-bg1">
          sidebar
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          content
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

And I deployed to Vercel [here](https://jaysportfolio.vercel.app/).

The problem I'm having now is the image doesn't stay centered when I resize. I tried the `object-cover` class too, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following style for the image, I tried it on your website using dev tools and it works.

```
.bg-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Further Suggestions:

- You are putting the image to include the entire page (including side
  content), you can better put the image tag inside the main content div
  and make its position: relative;  so that the image is
  contained inside the main content div only (and not the entire page
  while side content isn't transparent)

Hence you main content div would be like the following.

```
<div
  className="flex flex-col flex-grow"
  style={{
    position: "relative",
  }}
>
  <Image src={coverImg} alt="Cover Image" className="bg-img" />
  {/* Other main content divs children here */}
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!I published the change if you want to check it out

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, glad it helped! @Designly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the full-screen image is often achieved with `background-image`. But you can also achieve this with `<img>` (in your case, `<Image />` component from Next.js) by using [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property:

```html
<div className="overflow-hidden">
  <Image
    src={coverImg}
    alt="Cover Image"
    className="object-cover"
    fill
  />
</div>
```

The `object-cover` is a [Tailwind CSS utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit) and it gives the image a similar effect to using `background-image`'s with `cover` and `center`.

Here is a background-image version:

```html
<div className='bg-[url("/cover-img.jpg")] absolute left-0 top-0 h-screen w-screen bg-cover bg-center'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi
  dignissimos esse corrupti eaque, iusto, optio pariatur eos consectetur
  odio voluptas fugiat ad aperiam id rerum at quos dolores consequatur
  consequuntur.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not quite what I needed. I updated my answer in much greater detail.

Comment: Can you put together an example on codesanbox? I'm not able to reproduce your issue on your Vercel app. And since you want the image to be full screen, you shouldn't have specified width and height to it and instead should just use `fill` prop together with `object-cover`

Comment: Funny you mentioned that I wasted a bunch of time putting this in code sandbox but couldn't get tailwind to work properly. I will try your suggestion again

Comment: A GitHub repo will also do :)

Comment: https://github.com/designly1/portfolio

Comment: Thanks for the repo. But after I added the `fill` prop and a className `object-cover` to the image. It is now staying in the center of the viewport (browser window). Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes object cover was the way to go.