# how can i set the image into a certain size box appear properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have written code like this :-

```
import React from 'react'

function OurCourse() {
  return (
    <div className='w-full '>
        <div className='w-full h-[390px]' style={{
            backgroundImage:'url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532012197267-da84d127e765?ixlib=rb-

4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80)',
            backgroundSize:'contain',
            backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
        }}>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default OurCourse
```

I want to set this background image according to the size of its div which is given in its className but the image that appear is like this after it runs

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

i can make the text but not the background image as it appears

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691463/how-do-i-create-a-static-background-image-using-nextjss-next-image/75692382#75692382)

Comment: Let CSS do the cropping and positioning for you - background-size: cover and position center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the url with an arbitrary value in TailwindCSS, so you don't have to use a combination of the style object and classes.  As mentioned in the comments, the best way to do what you want is to use the background-size property set to `cover`.

```js
function OurCourse() {
  return (
    <div className="h-[390px] bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532012197267-da84d127e765?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=90')] grid place-content-center"> 
      <h1 className="text-white font-serif text-2xl">Our Courses</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<OurCourse />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, try not to use w-full or width: 100%.  The default 'auto' or natural behavior of block elements in HTML is to fill the available space 100%, so you should almost never need it.

Answer (score 0):

use the below CSS properties to the div for showing the center portion of the background image

```css
{background-position:center;background-size:cover}
```

***Sample Code***

```css
.h-390 {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532012197267-da84d127e765?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80);
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.text {
  top: 46%;
  left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='w-full h-390'>
  <div class="text">Our courses</div>
</div>
```